# Is "jux" a real word?

Tags: american-english, slang, is-it-a-word, caribbean-english

Urbandictionary.com says it means:

> To rob. Verb. Present tense of juxt.

It has 342 votes but I can't find any evidence of actual usage on a google or COCA search.

Comment: Try looking up the verb "[juke](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=juke)". (The past tense is actually "juked"). And "jux" is probably just how the third person singular is sometimes spelled while texting.

Comment: What’s your definition of a “real word”, anyway?

Comment: @tchrist It's not that important and becoming something of a distraction. I'm really after more information about usage of this word *jux*, a little etymology, maybe a stab at a better definition than those on UD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verb *to jux* as used in New York does mean *to rob*, for example to *rob someone* is to *jux a head*.

Here's a couple of sentences from the book Lush Life by Richard Price where he uses the word jux. Actually the word appears 8 times in the novel. From that it seems to me that it is a "real word" used in NYC.

> "Most project are kind of like, that's all they know, but you go two blocks in any direction from here, you go Wall Street, Chinatown, the Lower East Side, they are like release valves, you know? They give you the confidence to mix it up in the world -"
>   "And jux everybody in sight," Iacone murmured.
>   "You're so cynical, I swear to God," Yolanda said. "I was a projects kid, I didn't jux anybody"
>   ...
>   "How about a running buddy? Somebody he likes to jux heads with out there."

Comment: It's never too late if you have something new to add and this is exactly what I was looking for.  Although I'm not exactly sure about the context of "jux heads".  Does that still mean *to rob*?

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot to mention that in the book "jux" or "jux a head"means to rob somebody.

Answer (score 9):

### Summary

It appears *jux* (to rob) comes from Jamaican Patois *jooks* (to rob, especially with a pointed weapon), from Carribean *jook* (to poke) dating back to the early 19th century, and is similar to several west African words meaning to poke, pierce, prick or enter. *Jook* is now also London gang slang for theft or stabbing.

---

### Carribean use

Ras Dennis Jabari Reynolds' [*Jabari: Authentic Jamaican Dictionary of the Jamic Language*](http://books.google.com/books?id=LsNdtFF7b48C&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=jamaican%20%22jooks%22%20OR%20%22jook%22&source=bl&ots=1r2F1okYhk&sig=BX0CLW-ySG-4wTIxlGjdbvQpJu8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=w8k4UNfoEcrU4QTC9ICABA&ved=0CHsQ6AEwDDgU) (2006) gives prod and robbery definitions:

> **jook** (jük): v. to prod or poke; to engage in sexual intercourse
> **jook-out** (-owt, -ôt): v. to prod, so as to effect a protrusion; to project; to poke in the eye
> **jooks** (jüks): n./v. a robbery, usu. involving a weapon; to stay on point; to tarry

A [Rasta/Patois Dictionary and Phrases/Proverbs](http://niceup.com/patois.html#j) defines *jook* as:

> JOOK  :   to pierce or stick, as with a thorn or a long pointed stick. (5) also used in a sexual context (29)
>
> 5. Understanding Jamaican Patois, L. Emilie Adams, Kingston
> 29. Clinton Fearon - Original member of the Gladiators/Barbara Kennedy

[Partridge](http://books.google.com/books?id=cCVnlIUTpg4C&pg=PA373&lpg=PA373&dq=jamaican%20%22jooks%22%20OR%20%22jook%22&source=bl&ots=cROvT2MSgw&sig=oZtfrIN-YS9uktmZvGs7BegBu-g&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dcc4UNqNKujl4QT0h4GQCw&ved=0CJ4BEOgBMBI) (2007) includes:

> **joog** ***verb*** 1 to have sex. Sometimes spelt 'jewg' *JAMAICA 1942*
> **jook** ***noun*** sexual intercourse *TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO 1993*
> **jook** ***verb*** 1 to poke with a sharp object *BARBADOS, 1965*. 2 to stab *TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO 1827*

The OED says *jook* (also spelled *chook, juck, juick* and *juk*) is a Caribbean word meaning *to stab, pierce or poke* and gives a quotation from H. G. Murray's *Tom Kittle's Wake* (1877):

> Wen me see him so wid de begnet..me ting say de man da go jook me wid it.

And gives an etymology suggesting a west African source:

> Origin uncertain. Compare e.g. Fulani jukka to poke, Cameroon Pidgin English čuk-am to pierce, prick, Nigerian Pidgin English chook to pierce, prick, Mende jɔkɔ to enter.

The [Dictionary of the English/Creole of Trinidad & Tobago](http://books.google.fi/books?id=_n82hsbDJBMC&pg=PA471&lpg=PA471&dq=poke%20%22jooks%22%20OR%20%22jook%22&source=bl&ots=zmR3a25yJe&sig=hXBb-kXDIWiPq3w2BRIhmvSME4k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6NU4UK-EConl4QSV0ICIDw&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=jook&f=true) (2009) includes eight long entries for *jook* with many citations, with meanings from: to stab; to shove; to wash clothes with a sharp motion against a washboard(a *jooking board*); a (pelvic) thrust; a cut from a stabbing; a small quick attempt at something to see if you like it; sexual intercourse. The earliest quote is from 1827, for *stab*:

> Someting chook for my kin like one fork O!

A *jooker* is any sharp pointed thing. *Jook up* is to shove something sharpy; to push severely or repeatedly, to beat up. A *jook waist* is a sideways hip shift with the ribcage lifted away from the pelvic region, which is sharply pushed outwards. And:

> **jook out eye** *phr* Steal from; swindle; cheat someone. If you don't watch dem good, dem people go jook out yuh eye.

Anita M. Waters' [*Race, Class, and Political Symbols: Rastafari and Reggae in Jamaican Politics*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=Z3tmxS6La_EC&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=jamaican%20%22jooks%22%20OR%20%22jook%22&source=bl&ots=Xpqz_eJOU-&sig=gDMrq1Gs6sxpU3VP4Mz61Cx8GrE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5dM4UN2LMOem4gTUgoDIDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=jook&f=false) (1985) prints the lyrics of Neville Martin's 1976 election song "The Message" and says:

> ... used a popular slang phrase of the time, "jook them," meaning impress them or hit them

(Tangentially, Elaine B. Richardson's [*Hiphop Literacies*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=nHHaJ1qXspkC&pg=PT64&lpg=PT64&dq=poke%20%22jooks%22%20OR%20%22jook%22&source=bl&ots=HCDBXiktId&sig=phAsRNLxN-bC8aTqCUdx8LeTON8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6NU4UK-EConl4QSV0ICIDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=jook&f=true) (2006) notes the roots of *jukebox* is the *jook joint*, a place for rowdy dancing, and comes from Wolof *dzug* and Bambara *dzugu* meaning to "act disorderly" and "wicked". Richardson also says the *Dictionary of Jamaican English* (Cassidy and Le Page, 2002) traces it to Fulani *jukka* (spur, poke; knock down) and Cameroon pidgin (cuk used to mean pierce, prick), noting in one sense it "usually done suddenly", and another is the vulgar usage "to have sexual intercourse (with a woman)".)

---

### US slang

A 2005 edition of US urban music [*Vibe Magazine*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=-SYEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=jamaican%20%22jooks%22%20OR%20%22jook%22&source=bl&ots=Jy8aHxkOe2&sig=VYlGotgDM6Y0sNn9gusaUZd4HsU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=w8k4UNfoEcrU4QTC9ICABA&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=jook&f=false) included a guide to 1995-era slang:

> **rob:** jook; run a manip; run up on

Kermit Ernest Campbell's [*Gettin' Our Groove On: Rhetoric, Language, And Literacy For The Hip Hop Generation*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=gjsjb0QGCJIC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=%22African%20american%22%20slang%20%22jook%22&source=bl&ots=kh-pghbhmp&sig=yW93o1eH0eS1sohHJYCy6J99RPs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lOQ4UIq8HuT54QSm84G4Bw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=jook&f=false) (2005) says:

> In "Ebonics," for example, Big L offers a brief glossay of some comon (especially for the East Coast or New York) Hip hop expressions.
>
> > Yo, yo, a burglary is a jook, a woof's a crook
> > Mobb Deep already explained the meanin' of shook

---

### London slang

Herbert C. Covey's [*Street Gangs Throughout the World*](http://books.google.fi/books?id=6ZA2-JroF30C&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90&dq=jamaican%20%22jooks%22%20OR%20%22jook%22&source=bl&ots=LjJJycYGPN&sig=MH3btJyOpTJpFAbEe7sEjjz453A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dcc4UNqNKujl4QT0h4GQCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=jook&f=false) (2010) describes a 2002 journalistic account of a street gang from Peckham, London:

> Gang members were known to “jook” victims, which means stab them in the leg to hurt and terrorize them.

[Fearless](http://www.fearless.org/theft/theft/other-names) (part of the UK charity, Crimestoppers) says:

> Other names for theft include: stealing, five finger discount, clepto, hustle, scam, fraud, rob, take, jacking, shoplift, burgle, **jook,** mugging, pickpocketing, shoplifting, housebreaking.

It's listed on [*A lexicon of teen speak*](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/4074004.stm) by the BBC (2005):

> **jook** - to stab or to steal.
> *(Suggested by reader Caroline Jones, Godalming)*

And on the student-authored [London Slang Dictionary](http://eastlondondictionary.wetpaint.com/) (2008):

> jook - to stab or to steal.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on your definition of "real word".

You gave a word, a definition, and clearly, if it's in the urban dictionary, someone, somewhere is or has used the word with the meaning you described.

My own searching has shown two alternate definitions:

1) short for juxtaposed

2) a word adopted from German (English has a vast tendency to adopt words from other languages) meaning "fun, laughter, joke or jest"

If this is "enough evidence" for it to be a "real word", then it is.  If you prefer a different kind of source (like the OED), then it is not a "real word".

Unfortunately, the standard is not agreed upon, which is why sites like Urban dictionary exist: to capture the meanings of some words that aren't in other dictionaries.

Comment: It is not "enough evidence". I'd like to see the word used in context, in real speech or text.  The examples on urban dictionary are contrived.

Comment: I think your use of “other standard dictionaries” should be only either “other dictionaries” or “standard dictionaries”.

Comment: @tchrist I think people know what I meant by that, but it did bother me a bit, so since you agree, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an American, (stated since this question was tagged [american-english] ) and have never heard the word "jux" in any context, so I'd say <s>it's not a "real word"</s> that I wouldn't have considered it a real word until reading the other answers here. That's not to say that whoever put it in Urban Dictionary made it up. It might be a regionalism, but I have no idea what region that might be.